# How to access variable using a Ruby method call?

Tags: ruby, closures

I am new to Ruby and don't know how to access data members within a function (syntax-wise). Here is my question. I have a function that will put values into an array of numbers, from a user given range, that are prime. The function looks like so:

```
#Search for primes within a range
def find_primes(starting, ending)

    #Make an empty array
    a = []

    for x in starting..ending
        if is_prime(x)
            a << x #Store results in array
        end
    end

    yield
end
```

The catch is that I must use the yield keyword to call another function to get the data from array 'a'. For example, I need to print out consecutive prime numbers, that are stored in 'a', and I have this code to do this (except I don't know how to get at the values of 'a' from the code below. This is called closure, I believe)

```
find_primes(0,50) do 

    i = 0

    while i < a.size - 1
        print "[#{a[i]} #{a[i+1]} "
    end
end
```

This is all very new to me and I can't find a good source on how to do what I am tasked to do. Thank you in advance

Comment: good to see - [`Prime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html) also.

Answer (score 1):

You have a whole wrong idea. Using `for` in Ruby is code smell. This is how you do it if you want the iterator built in:

```
def find_primes(starting, ending, &pr)
  (starting..ending).select{|x| is_prime(x)}.each(&pr)
end

find_primes(1, 10){|x| puts x}
```

But the code above lacks flexibility. For flexibility, you should just make it return an array (or an enumerator). Then, you can use different iterators:

```
def find_primes(starting, ending)
  (starting..ending).select{|x| is_prime(x)}
end

find_primes(1, 10).each{|x| puts x}
find_primes(1, 10).each_cons(2){|x, y| puts "#{x} #{y}"}
```

Comment: I believe you have the wrong idea, I need to pass in a block of code into the function 'find_primes' implicitly to manipulate the data. Even if this is inefficient, its the way I was told to do this

Comment: What do you mean by "implicitly pass in a block of code"?

Comment: I take back my previous comment, I think you did in fact answer this but I didn't recognize it. Ruby syntax problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the variable a to the block you should use `yield a` instead of `yield`, then you can use find_primes like so:

```
require 'prime'

def find_primes(from, to)
  yield (from..to).select { |n| Prime.prime? n }
end

find_primes(0, 10) do |primes|
  p primes # => [2, 3, 5, 7]
end
```

Having said that, you can just use find_primes to return the array like a normal method if you want. You don't have to use yield with blocks. That is:

```
def find_primes(from, to)
  (from..to).select { |n| Prime.prime? n }
end

primes = find_primes(0,10)
# Do something with primes
```